# Getting sound from from both speakers in Swift 3

Tags: swift, audio

I'm having some issues with getting sound from both of my speakers. I used this code to implement the sound:

```
 if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "note1", withExtension: "wav") {
        var mySound: SystemSoundID = 0
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL as CFURL, &mySound)
        // Play
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
    }
```

Is it supposed to only play from one speaker on the computer?

Please be gentle with me, I'm totally new to programming :)
Thanks!

Best regards

Comment: I'm no AudioServices expert, but I think it will play in whatever format the wav resource is; i.e. mono or stereo.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, so maybe thats it :)
Thanks :)

Comment: There should be a way to play the single channel of a monoaural resource in both channels of the output... again, just speculating.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. I re-wrote the code, at it worked perfectly.... :)

Comment: Great! Perhaps you can answer your own question (with the actual, rewritten code), so it helps other people in the future.

Comment: Yes, of course! Thanks for reminding me :)

Answer (score 0):

Heres is the code, for those who want it:

import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController{

```
let soundArray = ["note1", "note2", "note3", "note4", "note5", "note6", "note7"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}



@IBAction func notePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    playingSound(soundFileName: soundArray[sender.tag - 1])


    }

func playingSound(soundFileName : String) {

     if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundFileName, withExtension: "wav") {
        var mySound: SystemSoundID = 0
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL as CFURL, &mySound)
        // Play
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
    }

}

}
```